# Select case <> with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, case, vba

I have the code below for a case statement however it only works for the first argument (debug.prints sheet2 and 3, please can someone assist

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.CodeName
            Case Is <> "Sheet1", "Sheet2"
                Debug.Print ws.CodeName
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: That is a good question. I have verified what the OP is saying doesn't work.

Comment: Case can take a comma-delimited list of expressions, any one of which can trigger the case. I suspect your code is being interpreted as `Case (Is <> "Sheet1"), "Sheet2"`. So anything not Sheet1 will fall within the case, AND Sheet2 will fall within the case.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain why that is not working but here is a work around. You can do it as an empty case and then do your actions in the case else.

```
Sub test()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.CodeName
        Case "Sheet1" To "Sheet2"

        Case Else
        Debug.Print ws.CodeName
    End Select
Next ws
End Sub
```

Or you could just test with an if statement instead of a case.

```
If ws.CodeName <> "Sheet1" AND ws.CodeName <> "Sheet2" then
    Debug.Print ws.CodeName
End if
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        Select Case ws.CodeName
            Case Is <> "Sheet1", Is <> "Sheet2"
                Debug.Print ws.CodeName
        End Select
    Next ws
End Sub
```